# Null Pointer Exception adding null check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Simple and best way to solve Null pointer exception at this line:

```
oS = ((SyIntBVO)syIntBVOList.get(0)).getSource().trim();
```

Exception on getSource variable. how to add null check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how "defensive" you need your code to be, technically you *could* need to check for `null` on anything that potentially *could* be `null`.  At the extreme case, this is any object you de-reference.  For example...

Can `syIntBVOList` be `null`?  Then you need to check it before you de-reference it:

```
if (syIntBVOList == null) {
    return;
}
SomeType variable = syIntBVOList.get(0);
```

Can `variable` be `null`?  Can its casted version be `null`?

```
SyIntBVO anotherVariable = ((SyIntBVO)variable);
if (anotherVariable == null) {
    return;
}
```

Can `getSource()` return `null`?  Same pattern.  And so on...

It's really up to your code what can or can not potentially be `null`.  If any of these instances of an object, whether stored in a variable or referenced directly in-line, can be `null` then you would want to check for that `null` reference before de-referencing it.

(Note: It's often considered an anti-pattern for a method which *should* return an instance to sometimes return `null`.  For exactly this reason, because it requires consuming code to be this defensive.)

Answer (score 1):

```
String oS = ((SyIntBVO)syIntBVOList.get(0)).getSource();

if(os != null) {
    os = oS.trim(); // we're good
} else {
    // deal with null
}
```

Or, if `get(0)` returns null, this will work:

```
SyIntBVO syIntBvo = ((SyIntBVO)syIntBVOList.get(0));

if(syIntBvo != null) {
    String os = SyIntBvo.getSource().trim(); // we're good
} else {
    // deal with null
}
```

To decide which one you need we require more details, e.g. a stack trace.

Comment: .getSource() returning null?

Comment: Then the first solution will help you